# skip_blank_lines not working with Pandas 0.13.x

Tags: python, pandas

When using pandas read_table (version 0.13.1), I'm getting the following error

```
data = pd.read_table(filename, header=0, sep=r'\s+', skip_blank_lines=True)
```

> parser_f() got an unexpected keyword argument 'skip_blank_lines'

Comment: Works fine in 0.15.2 so probably not implemented in 0.13.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the docs for 0.13.1's [read_table](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.13.1/generated/pandas.read_table.html#pandas.read_table) show, there *is* no `skip_blank_lines` argument.

That wasn't introduced until [0.15.0](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.15.0/generated/pandas.read_table.html#pandas.read_table):

```
skip_blank_lines : boolean, default True
    If True, skip over blank lines rather than interpreting as NaN values
```