# Issues with pandas install - running several versions of python

Tags: python, pandas, snakemake

I'm having issues with installing the panda library. I'm currently using snakemake with Python version 2.7 and 3.4 under LMDE.
I've tried the following:

```
pip install pandas
```

which doesn't work, as I get the following error:

```
No module named 'pandas'
```

I figured it is because snakemake is based on python 3, and I tried solutions from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18926696/python3-and-pandas).
This one not working (I don't quite get the concept of virtualenv anyway):

```
apt-get install python-virtualenv virtualenvwrapper
mkvirtualenv -p python3 pandas_env
pip install pandas
```

Then I tried:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pandas
```

It worked fine but then I got this error:

```
parser_f() got an unexpected keyword argument 'skip_blank_lines'
```

From [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29129192/skip-blank-lines-not-working-with-pandas) it looks like a version problem, which should be > 0.15. Last command said it installed pandas 0.14, but when I checked here's what I got:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> pd.__version__
'0.16.2'
```

I'm getting stuck here, between python versions and pandas versions I don't know what to do. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `import os,pandas` and `print os.path.dirname(pandas.__file__)` @rioualen and delete question for duplicate !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK so it seems it makes a difference to install a python lib with pip whether I use sudo as myself or as root?...

I had done

```
$ sudo pip install pandas
```

Now I did

```
$ sudo pip uninstall pandas
$ su -
# pip install pandas
```

And now it seems to work perfectly fine! Is this normal though?

Comment: be specific. I really need an answer for this

Answer (score 0):

The point of `virtualenv` is to allow the same Python system to maintain multiple project environments independently of each other. Having created your virtual environment the `pip install pandas` command (which apparently worked) was all you needed - have you tried starting up Python and importing the module?

The `sudo apt-get install python3-pandas` command would attempt to install the Python 3 pandas module. It's rarely a good idea to mess with the system-installed Python (which is precisely why `virtualenv` is such a great idea).

If you `pip uninstall pandas` in your virtual environment you should be able to run `pip install "pandas<16.0"` to get an older version.

Comment: Thanks, it seemingly solved my previous problems, but now I get yet another error:
`'module' object has no attribute 'DataFrame'`
The error is rising in the following function: 
`def read_table(file:str, verbosity:int=0, header:int=0, skip_blank_lines=True, comment=';') -> pd.DataFrame:
        if verbosity >= 4:
        print ("read_table()\t" + file)
    df = pd.read_csv(file, sep="\t", 
                     header=header, 
                     skip_blank_lines=skip_blank_lines,
                     comment=comment)
    return(df)`
This code was written by a colleague and it should work...

Comment: As you can see, it isn't easy to read large blocks of code in comments! The error message implies that you have imported a module with the name `pd`, but that module isn't `pandas`, which definitely DOES have a `DataFrame` attribute.

Comment: Hm, I'm starting to think the latter problem might be related to my input file, gonna investigate that...
Thank you again.